# ellipses collisions in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ellipse, collision

I'm facing some problems in my game
in fact I had to detect an ellipse-ellipse collision
I'll prefer codes in vb.net language as I can't understand any other one
any helps with ideas or codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check collisions with `Region` objects and `Region.Intersect` method:

```
Dim gp1 As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
gp1.AddEllipse(rect1)

Dim gp2 As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
gp2.AddEllipse(rect2)

Dim reg1 As New Region(gp1)
Dim reg2 As New Region(gp2)

reg1.Intersect(reg2)

If reg1.GetRegionScans(New Drawing2D.Matrix(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)).Length > 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Collision!")
End If
```

In this example `rect1` and `rect2` are `Rectangle`s that define (contain) the ellipses, like when you draw the ellipses with a rectangle:

```
Dim rect1 As New Rectangle(5, 5, 150, 100)
Me.CreateGraphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, rect1)
```

**EDIT:**

For performance and options you better use a game engine. Check this links:

- [Table of game engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) with information about each one and links
- List of [game engines for Vb.NET](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/183852-game-engines-for-vbnet/)

Comment: thanks friend , but this is really slow , I can't use it in my game doing it for 5 times only makes the fps less than 50 !!!
I need at lest about 100 collisions detections
in fact it's not efficient enough to be used in game programing
any other ideas ??

Comment: I dont think there is a more efficient way. You can do your own maths to check the collisions, that will improve the performance. Just search on google for "ellipse collision". Other fast option might be checking the collision of the rectangles with `rect1.IntersectWith(rect2)` but it will check all the rectangle area not only the ellipse area.

Comment: If you want performance you should use a proper game engine and not using this cause is not optimized for game developing. Dont except good methods to doing the job here. In a good engine you will have all you need to check everything efficiently.

Comment: in fact , you are right in your suggest (to use a game engine) , but I couldn't find a good engine for 2d games in vb.net , so I decided I'll make my own one , let's hope I could do it :) , thanks really for help :)